# Error when using .fit_generator on Siamese CNN

Tags: python, keras, computer-vision, generator, conv-neural-network

we are trying to fit a Siamese CNN and are experiencing troubles on the last part where we want to use .fit_generator to supply the data into the model.

Our generator function looks like this:

```
def get_batch(h, w, batch_size = 100):

    anchor =np.zeros((batch_size,h,w,3))
    positive =np.zeros((batch_size,h,w,3))
    negative =np.zeros((batch_size,h,w,3))

    while True:
    #Choose index at random
        index = np.random.choice(n_row, batch_size)
        for i in range(batch_size):
            list_ind = train_triplets.iloc[index[i],]
            #print(list_ind)
            anchor[i] =  train_data[list_ind[0]]
            positive[i] = train_data[list_ind[1]]
            negative[i] = train_data[list_ind[2]]

            anchor = anchor.astype("float32")
            positive = positive.astype("float32")
            negative = negative.astype("float32")

        yield [anchor,positive,negative]
```

The model expects to get a list of 3 arrays as input for the Siamese CNN. However, we get the following
error message:

```
Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 3 array(s), but instead got the following list of 1 arrays
```

If we simply supply a list with the 3 arrays by hand then it works. So thats why we suspect the error to be caused by the .fit_generator function. We have to use the .fit_generator function since we cannot store out data because of memory issues.

**Anybody knows why that is?**

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error, the model expects 3 arrays and NOT a list of 3 arrays. So changing
`yield [anchor,positive,negative]` to `yield anchor,positive,negative` might work.